# Unable to derive specific probability density function, from a given other probability density function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm given an absolutely continuous stochastic variable $U$, with the probability density function $f_{U}$ given by;
$$
f_{U}\left(u\right) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
2u & \text{ if } u \in \left] 0,1 \right[ \\
0  & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

My task is now to derive the probability density function for $X = e^{U}$. I've tried different approaches, however I'm unable to get the expected result of;
$$
f_{X}\left(x\right) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{2 \cdot \ln\left(x\right)}{x} & \text{ if } x \in \left] 1,e \right[ \\
0  & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

**Edit:**

Found another exercise alike this one (which seems simpler)

I'm given an stochastic variable $Y \sim R\left(0,1\right)$, with the probability density function $f_{Y}$ given by;
$$
f_{Y}\left(y\right) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \text{ if } y \in \left]0,1\right[ \\
0 & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

My task is now to derive the probability density function for $Z = Y^{3}$. Again without any luck I've tried different approaches, and I'm unable to reach the expected result of;
$$
f_{Z}\left(z\right) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{3} \cdot z^{-\frac{2}{3}} & \text{ if } z \in \left]0,1\right[ \\
0  & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

**Note**

So far I've been able to determine the correct intervals, using the method @DilipSarwate.

After I figured, that I was integrating, rather than differentiating (thanks to @JonathanY.), I'm able to get the first exercise, to get the correct answer, the second is however troublesome:

Differentiating $z^{\frac{1}{3}}$ yields $\frac{1}{3} \cdot z^{\frac{2}{3}}$, and not; $\frac{1}{3} \cdot z^{-\frac{2}{3}}$

**Question**

What should I do in order to reach the correct result (please see discussion on the answer)?

Comment: **Differentiating $z^{\frac{1}{3}}$ yields $\frac{1}{3} \cdot z^{\frac{2}{3}}$, and not $\frac{1}{3} \cdot z^{-\frac{2}{3}}$**.        True or False: For $a \neq 0$, the derivative of $x^a$ is $ax^{a-1}$ ??

Comment: The last statement is true, and I do believe that the differential of $z^{\frac{1}{3}$ is correct, but if this is the case, then my expected result, must be wrong, can you confirm this?

Comment: Another Question: Does $\frac{1}{3} - 1$ equal $\frac{2}{3}$ or does it equal $-\frac{2}{3}$?  If the latter, what does setting $a = \frac{1}{3}$ in the statement $$\frac{d}{dz}z^{a} = az^{a-1}$$ yield as the derivative of $z^{\frac{1}{3}}?\ \ $ $\frac{1}{3}z^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ or $\frac{1}{3}z^{\frac{2}{3}}$ as you have repeatedly insisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, figure out what values $X = e^U$ can take on in view of the given information about $U$.

Next, write
$$F_X(x) = P\{X \leq x\} = P\{e^U \leq x\} = P\{U \leq g(x)\} = F_U(g(x))$$
where *you* should figure out what $g(x)$ is.

Then, write

$$f_X(x) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}F_X(x) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}F_U(g(x))
= f_U(g(x))\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}g(x)$$
where once again you need to figure out the derivative of $g(x)$. If the last
equality confuses you recall the chain rule for differentiation from basic
calculus.

---

Applying the idea above, if $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, then
$Y = X^3$ also takes on values in $(0,1)$ and so for
$0 < y < 1$, $Y$ has distribution function
$$F_Y(y) = P\{Y \leq y\} = P\{X^3 \leq y\} = P\{X \leq y^\frac{1}{3}\} 
= F_X(y^\frac{1}{3})$$ and so,
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}F_Y(y) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}
F_X(y^\frac{1}{3}) = f_X(y^\frac{1}{3})\cdot \frac{1}{3}y^{-\frac{2}{3}}
= \frac{1}{3}y^{-\frac{2}{3}}, 0 < y < 1.$$
Here we have used the chain rule for differentiation and the facts that 
$f_X(\cdot)$ has constant value $1$ for arguments in $(0,1)$, and
that for $a \neq 0$,
$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}y^a = ay^{a-1} = \frac{1}{3}y^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ when
$a = \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: <quote>First, figure out what values $X = e^U$ can take on in view of the given information about $U$.</quote> I've already tried this, by setting $u$ to it's limits (0, and 1), which yields the limits $1$ and $e^{2}$ for $x$ ($e^{2} \neq e$)?

Comment: In ordinary mathematical discourse, the symbol $e$, unless explicitly defined to mean something else, usually means the base of the natural logarithms; and so $e^2 \neq e$.  Also, I don't understand how you get that $e^U = e^2$ when $U = 1$. Could you explain further?

Comment: The $e$ is indeed the base of natural logarithms. And as for why I got $e^{2}$, that's because I've translated $e^{U}$ to $e^{2*u}$ and then used my values as $u$, should I be using my values for $e^{U}$?

Comment: @Skeen $X = e^U$ and so if $U = 1$, $X = e$, no? Why should the result be any different if you are given additional information to distract you (such as density function of $U$)?

Comment: @Skeen If $U$ were _uniformly_ distributed on $]0,1[$ so that $f_U(u) = 1$ for $u \in ]0,1[$, would you say that $e^U$ would have value $e^1$ both when $X = 0$ and when $X=1$, and indeed for all intermediate values as well?

Comment: Without the additional information to distract you, how would I get  the limits for $U$, which I use to find the limits for $X$?

Comment: So what I'm getting is that $g\left(x\right) = \ln\left(x\right)$? - and the derivative of $\int g\left(x\right) = x \cdot \ln\left(x\right) - x$? - and $f_{U}\left(g\left(x\right)\right) \cdot \frac{d}{dx} g\left(x\right) = 2 \cdot \ln\left(x\right) \cdot \left(x \cdot \ln\left(x\right) - x\right)$? - This does however not match $\frac{2 \cdot \ln\left(x\right)}{x}$?

Comment: Also I clearly get your point, why it is $U$ and not $f_{U}\left(u\right)$ to use the limits for.

Comment: You've confused derivative with anti-derivative. Differentiate $\ln(x)$ to get $\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Oh, I performed integration, that than differentation!

Comment: Edit to previous post; rather than*